# How to use PersistentVolumeClaim if replicas attribute value is greater than 1?

Tags: kubernetes

In my StatefulSet deployment specification, I have 'replicas' defined as 2. Now I want to use Persistent Volume (PV) and Persistent Volume Claims (PVC), for which I created one PV (dynamic provisioning using StorageClass) and one PVC which I then used in my deployment spec. I am testing the deployment on AWS.

The problem is that only one node is able to get attached to the PV using the PVC. Even if I create multiple PVs and PVCs for each node, I am not sure how to use them in the deployment spec so that each node picks a different PV.

Error:

```
Multi-Attach error for volume "pvc-ec99e704-f72e-11e7-87a6-065468f047a0" Volume is already exclusively attached to one node and can't be attached to another
```

Any pointer will help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are two issues you're facing here.

For starters, AWS EBS can be attached to one node exclusively, o can't have the same PVC/PV couple for multiple PODs (what is called a ROX or RWX mode).

Secondly, for scaled deployments/statefullsets etc. there is a special way to declare PVC in a way that is "dynamic" called volumeClaimTemplate.

```
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: myname
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
```

With this, whenever scaled, your pods will create/remove matching PVCs automatically.

This use case really calls for support of automatic PV provisioning though, to be really usefull, meaning you either need to be on a supported cloud provider or use another mechanism like GlusterFS with [Heketi](https://github.com/heketi/heketi)

Comment: I'll accept your answer since that's exactly what I did to solve the problem.

Comment: One question though, if I don't have PV created from before in AWS then I am getting "PersistentVolumeClaim is not bound" error for Pods and 'no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set' error for PVC. I guess you already mentioned that we need automatic provisioning support. Are not 'StorageClass' for the same purpose?

Comment: I downvoted because this is a case of 'statically' provisioned PVs vs dynamically provisioned. This last one is, let's say, 'easier' to do and well-known but I too have the same problem as the person who asked the question: I have an STS with 2+ replicas, I have PVs and PVC created , but I cannot find a way to tell the STS to use more than one PV/PVC. "Even if I create multiple PVs and PVCs for each node, I am not sure how to use them in the deployment spec so that each node picks a different PV." Does anyone know? Thx

Comment: not that it bothers me much, but it did solve the original issue. Plus this is by no means a response that promotes dynamic pv, this is an answer using staticaly provisioned PVs, only the PVCs are created dynamicaly using template. It has in fact nothing to do with dynamic provisioning of PVs which is a completely separate mechanism depending on particular cluster / cloud-provider